# Can't install a program again after deleting its files

Tags: uninstall

My Problem is that I installed a program in my PC some days ago and then when i needed to remove it, i simply deleted its files rather than manually uninstalling it. Now when i try to install it, it prompts me whether to uninstall previously installed files or not, when i click yes, it shows an error message that it was unable to uninstall. I also looked up its keys in the windows registry, but it wasn't there. Please help me.

Sorry for bad English :)

Comment: You could install the program on another PC and copy those files over.

Comment: Remove all traces of the software in the windows registry using regedit.

Comment: Can you provide that program link?

Answer (score 1):

Download and install
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).

It might be able to delete all left-over traces of the installed program,
even after the uninstaller will fail.
Set the Scan option to maximal.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc This helped a ton. The registry files were messing up with the reinstallation of my Unity Hub.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because your Windows thinks it is installed, because it have program installer (have an entry in "Programs and functions" in control panel).

Try uninstalling program from "Programs and functions" and then reinstall it once again.

Comment: Windows is not concerned with that. If a program complains it is already installed, that’s the program’s installer, not Windows.

Comment: There is a small chance that installer checks for some entries in Windows or that the installer referenced in Programs and functions is slightly different.

Comment: I have already tried going to programs and features. It opens the same uninstaller that shows the error message so its of no use

Answer (score -1):

Your computer might still think that the program is installed. Go to Settings -> Add or remove programs (accessible by searching in the start menu) and search the program name. If it is there, try to uninstall it.

Comment: It opens the same uninstaller which shows the error message, so again its of no use.

Comment: How is this any different from the earlier answer?